# Matching just one line in a document, then replacing the digits in that line using bash on Ubuntu

Tags: regex, bash, ubuntu, sed, nested

I have a file 'lines.txt' with content:

```
SomeLine=string
PeopleCharms=007
OtherLine=667
PeopleCount=19
MoreLines%=0
AndYetMore%=34HG711
```

Using a bash script on Ubuntu 14.04 called 'change.sh' I would like to replace the "19" in the Line "PeopleCount=" with another number which I have as a variable.

The internet :-) suggests that

```
sed -i '/^PeopleCount/ s/\d+/$var/g' lines.txt
```

should do the trick. But it doesn't. I also tried Expresso to see what I can get to work but of course these tools are not clever enough to anticipate what I wante... yet.
(and just to make sure that the variable is not the issue, I also used static numbers just to see whether it works)

Can it be done in one regex? Many thanks for any help!

Comment: With your idea: `sed -i '/^PeopleCount=/ s/[0-9]\+/'"$var"'/' file`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

very few tools will recognize `\d` as representing a digit (so use `[0-9]` instead when necessary) and shell won't expand variables within single quotes. Try this:

```
sed -i 's/^\(PeopleCount=\).*/\1'"$var"'/' lines.txt
```

Comment: Why not double quote the whole command? `sed -i "/^\(PeopleCount=\).*/\1$var/" lines.txt`.

Comment: @Kenavoz Because it opens the whole command up to interpretation by the shell and so then you need to worry about what the shell might do with it, e.g. if your command contains a `$` sign you'd have to escape it. No matter what tool it is, never put any UNIX script in double quotes, put all scripts in single quotes and just break them open for shell access around  the minimal spot necessary.

Comment: Plus 1 but awk also works well: ` gawk -F= -v "x=$var" -i inplace '$1=="PeopleCount" {$2=x} 1' OFS==  lines.txt`

Comment: @John1024 thanks and yeah but seds simpler plus fairly robust, efficient, and portable in this case.

Comment: @EdMorton I will print this last comment :)

Comment: @Kenavoz horses for courses. If you're doing a simple substituion on an individual line, you should use sed. For anything else use awk of course :-).

Comment: Thank you Ed - my original idea might have had it's root in Ruby, good to know that they don't all migrate ;-) Sadly the command you proposed not only means I no longer understand the code (that can be adjusted with some more reaearch of course) but also - it does not change the line in my file at all. Neither, I hasten  to add, does Cyrus' proposal :-(

Comment: Ignore my last comment. Classic finger trouble. My apologies. Yes. That works. Both of those work. I understand one fully so I'll stick with that one from Cyrus. But the other one is good learning material. Thanks a lot!!